# Sorting list by time slots in Android and Check new time slot with older one

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

I am writing one meeting application in Android. In this application user can enter the future date and time slots. Time slot means it will be in pair (i.e. 2:00 PM to 3:00 PM or 1:45 PM to 2:15 PM). So, my question is when user will enter the new time slot then it should not conflict with older time slot or previously entered time slots.
i.e. There are 3 fields are there in my ArrayList. date, fromTime, toTime. 
So, suppose user has already created meeting on these time slots:

```
22/09/2017  11:00 AM  to  11:45 AM
22/09/2017  11:55 AM  to  12:30 PM
22/09/2017  12:50 PM  to  01:30 PM
22/09/2017  04:30 PM  to  05:30 PM
```

So, after that user can insert only time slots which will not effect or conflict with above ones.

```
i.e.
02:00 PM to 3:00 PM 
03:30 PM to 04:15 PM <-- These two time slots can be valid but

it can't be like this 
11:30 AM to 12:00 PM
12:15 PM to 12:40 PM
```

Please help me with it. Thanks in advance to every one.

Comment: Use Calendar class it has methods before and after. for new time slot you should check that start time not after old time slot start time and new time slot start time not before old time slot and time. Same for end time of new time slot

Comment: Issue is not having with date. The main issue is having with time slots and sorry bro I am not getting you what you are trying to explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save these slots as `<Date, Date>`  pairs you can check if new pair does not conflict with existing by using this approach:

```
  public class Pair {
    private Date from;
    private Date until;
    public Pair(Date from, Date until){
        this.from = from;
        this.until = until;
    }
    public Date getFrom(){ return from; }
    public Date getUntil(){ return until; }
    public void setFrom(Date from){ this.from = from; }
    public void setUntil(Date until){ this.until = until; }
}


List<Pair> listOfMeetings = getDefaultList();
Pair newPair = new Pair(dateFrom, DateUntil)

boolean hasConficts = false;

Calendar newFromCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar loopingFromCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar newUntilCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar loopingUntilCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

for(Pair p : listOfMeetings) {

    newFromCalendar.setTime(newPair.getFrom());
    loopingFromCalendar.setTime(p.getFrom());

    newUntilCalendar.setTime(newPair.getUntil());
    loopingUntilCalendar.setTime(p.getUntil());

    if (newFromCalendar.after(loopingFromCalendar) && newFromCalendar.before(loopingUntilCalendar) ) {
        hasConficts = true;
        break;
    }
    if (newUntilCalendar.after(loopingFromCalendar) && newUntilCalendar.before(loopingUntilCalendar) ) {
        hasConficts = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

in loop you check if new `From` or new `Until` is between existing `From-Until` pairs